# Weird error with Redis and Celery

Tags: python, redis, celery

I'm getting the following error in one of my Celery workers:

```
2015-07-21T15:02:04.010066+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-07-21T15:02:04.010069+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 296, in trace_task
2015-07-21T15:02:04.010070+00:00 app[worker.1]:     on_chord_part_return(task, state, R)
2015-07-21T15:02:04.010073+00:00 app[worker.1]:     deps.delete()
2015-07-21T15:02:04.010074+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 773, in delete
2015-07-21T15:02:04.010071+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 587, in on_chord_part_return
2015-07-21T15:02:04.010078+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 329, in delete_group
2015-07-21T15:02:04.010076+00:00 app[worker.1]:     (backend or self.app.backend).delete_group(self.id)
2015-07-21T15:02:04.010079+00:00 app[worker.1]:     return self._delete_group(group_id)
2015-07-21T15:02:04.010081+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 499, in _delete_group
2015-07-21T15:02:04.010082+00:00 app[worker.1]:     self.delete(self.get_key_for_group(group_id))
2015-07-21T15:02:04.010083+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 172, in delete
2015-07-21T15:02:04.010084+00:00 app[worker.1]:     self.client.delete(key)
2015-07-21T15:02:04.010085+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 824, in delete
2015-07-21T15:02:04.010087+00:00 app[worker.1]:     return self.execute_command('DEL', *names)
2015-07-21T15:02:04.010088+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 565, in execute_command
2015-07-21T15:02:04.010089+00:00 app[worker.1]:     return self.parse_response(connection, command_name, **options)
2015-07-21T15:02:04.010090+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 579, in parse_response
2015-07-21T15:02:04.010091+00:00 app[worker.1]:     return self.response_callbacks[command_name](response, **options)
2015-07-21T15:02:04.010093+00:00 app[worker.1]: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'QUEUED'
```

What I find weird is that I see no call to `int` in the last line of the stack trace. QUEUED probably came in as a worker's status. I'm using it as a custom worker status like this:

```
@before_task_publish.connect
def update_sent_state(sender=None, body=None, **kwargs):
    # the task may not exist if sent using `send_task` which
    # sends tasks by name, so fall back to the default result backend
    # if that is the case.
    task = current_app.tasks.get(sender)
    backend = task.backend if task else current_app.backend
    logging.debug("Setting status for %s" % body["id"])

    backend.store_result(body['id'], None, "QUEUED")
```

What could be the issue here?

---

In case it's relevant, here's the code for my task. I only call fetch directly is `fetch`.

```
@app.task
def fetch(url_or_urls, subscribe=None):
    """This fetches a (list of) podcast(s) and stores it in the db. It assumes that it only gets called
    by Podcast.get_by_url, or some other method that knows whether a given podcast has
    already been fetched.

    If *subscribe* is given, it should be a User instance to be subscribed to the given podcasts."""
    if isinstance(url_or_urls, basestring):
        url_or_urls = [url_or_urls]
    body = _store_podcasts.s()
    if subscribe:
        body.link(_subscribe_user.s(user=subscribe))
    return chord([_fetch_podcast_data.s(url) for url in url_or_urls])(body)

@app.task
def _fetch_podcast_data(url):
    return do_fetch(url) # This function returns a dict of podcast data.

@app.task
def _store_podcasts(podcasts_data):
    """Given a list of dictionaries representing podcasts, store them all in the database."""
    podcasts = [Podcast(**pdata) for pdata in podcasts_data]
    return Podcast.objects.insert(podcasts)

@app.task
def _subscribe_user(podcasts, user):
    """Subscribe the given users to all the podcasts in the list."""
    return user.subscribe_multi(podcasts)
```

Is there anything else that could be relevant here?

---

Library versions as shown by `pip freeze`:

```
redis==2.10.3
celery==3.1.18
```

Comment: Can you provide celery and redis-py version? I have some point to investigate, but your error trace line no is not same as mine.

Comment: @mrorno Versions as shown by `pip freeze`: `redis==2.10.3`, `celery==3.1.18`

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to debug such a bug without working code. Here is what i think it could be. 
Lets start here:

> http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/celery/backends/base.html#BaseBackend.store_result

```
def store_result(self, task_id, result, status,
                 traceback=None, request=None, **kwargs):
    """Update task state and result."""
    result = self.encode_result(result, status)
    self._store_result(task_id, result, status, traceback,
                       request=request, **kwargs)
    return result
```

It calls ecnode_result. Lets check that out

```
  def encode_result(self, result, status):
        if status in self.EXCEPTION_STATES and isinstance(result, Exception):
            return self.prepare_exception(result)
        else:
            return self.prepare_value(result)
```

It looks like "status" is expected to be something from predefined STATE constants.

Its code is here

> http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/celery/states.html#state

And docs here

> http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.states.html

That does not look like they expect to see something like  "QUEUED" there. Try one of the predefined.

Comment: Celery tasks have an `update_state()` method, where you can provide any string, I'm looking into that. Documentation: http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#custom-states

Comment: hmm `task.update_state` seems to do the exact same thing I'm doing: `self.backend.store_result(task_id, meta, state)`, where meta is None by default.

Comment: Could you try something of predefined states, so we can ensure the problem is where we are looking at.

Comment: Make sure this is also not your case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378628/python-redis-manager-worker-application-best-practices

Comment: I'm running the worker with `celery worker -A webapp.async.app -P eventlet -c 1000`, but since the Celery docs don't say that redis and eventlets don't work together, I'm assuming that Celery is taking care of this by pooling.

Answer (score 2):

The [redis python](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/blob/2.10.3/redis/client.py#L295) packages expects the response from the `DEL` action to always be an integer, which I assume is the count of deleted rows.

The call to int happens in the last line (`return  self.response_callbacks[command_name](response, **options)`) where `self.response_callbacks['DEL']` is equal to `int`.

As a workaround, you could subclass the `redis.client.StrictRedis` and set the `DEL` response callback to something other than `int`, just make sure you're familiar with the implications.

Comment: And why is it not getting an int? As far as I'm concerned, I'm not dealing with Redis, just Celery.

Comment: If you're calling it asynchronously its going to return a http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html.  Once the task is finished the actual result (probably the integer) will be accessible in the result attribute of that result.

Comment: Sure, and that result is stored in redis. It looks like Celery is doing some cleanup work, deleting intermediate group results, and somewhere in that proses, redis gets my task's status instead of the deletion count. How does that happen? In case it's relevant, I'll add the code for the task I'm calling to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error these days. And founded my `QUEUED` response comes from redis `MULTI` commands. See https://redis.io/topics/transactions#usage.

It maybe that your are reading response from wrong connection. Maybe in multi-processing / multi-threading / eventlet, etc. Not sure.

Comment: This would probably better left as a comment instead of an answer